# How to prevent Safari from offering translation for the primary language of the device?

Tags: macos, safari, internationalization, language, web-browsing

As the title is self-descriptive, despite my device's primary language is English, Safari still offers translations for the pages in English. How can I prevent Safari from offering translation for the primary language of the device? I could not find a preference for that.

p.s. I'm using the recently released *macOS Ventura*.

Comment: all web pages or just some

Comment: post a link where Safari wants to translate

Comment: For example, here. Or YouTube or Twitter. @Ruskes